# Change Label Generic Inline Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I the following in the models.py:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(_('date'), blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(_('description'), max_length=255)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, verbose_name=_('content type'))
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('object id'), db_index=True)
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class ItemAccountAmountRef(Item):
    """ Items of which a Quote or an Invoice exists. """
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    debit_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='receivables_receipt_debit_account')
    credit_account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='receivables_receipt_credit_account')

class PaymentItem(ItemAccountAmountRef):
    pass

class Payment(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ManyToManyField(Invoice, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField('date')
    attachments = generic.GenericRelation(Attachment)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, related_name='payment_site', null=True, blank=True
    items = generic.GenericRelation(PaymentItem)
```

in the admin.py:

```
class PaymentItemInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
    model = PaymentItem
    form = PaymentItemForm

class PaymentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PaymentItemInline]
```

in forms.py:

```
class PaymentItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaymentItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['credit_account'].label = "Bank Account"
```

In the PaymentItemInline the label is not changing. I have tried changing other attributes e.g. class which work. If I run through the init in debug mode I can see that the label variable is changing however when the form is rendered the field is still labelled credit account. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you cleared the browser cache?

Comment: Yes I have and it still give the same result sadly. On a different model I've now tried to change the onclick of a foreignkey dropdown but it only seems to work from the second inline onwards. I have a feeling this might be a Django problem but I could be mistaken. For now it looks like I'm going to have to go and make these changes through javascript as much as it pains me to do so.

Comment: Most likely it is *not* a "Django problem". It's not evident from the code you posted here where the error is, but I'd bet on it being your code before the open-source, community-reviewed, thoroughly tested and in mass deployment Django source. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're 98% of the way there.  Instead of trying to futz with the form field in `__init__`, just redefine it in your `ModelForm`.  If you name it the same thing, django will be able to figure out that it is supposed to validate & save to the `ForeignKey` field.  You can use the same formula to change a Field or Widget completely for a given field in a `ModelForm`.

You can find the default form field types for each model field type here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types

```
class PaymentItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    credit_account = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Bank Account", queryset=Account.objects.all())
```

That's it.  No need to override any functions at all : )

Incidentally, the docs for *this* field are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield